# What to do if node server falls down in container?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, uncaught-exception

If an `uncaughtException` occurs in Docker container running node app which is wrapped by Kubernetes Pod and due to this exception the server gets down, what should I do?

Comment: If you use ReplicaSet, then after the application crashes, the pod will also crash, as a result of which the ReplicaSet will create a new pod.

Comment: Yes, its deployed using a Deployment resource. The pod is actually do restarting by K8S. Its first getting Errored then ImagePullLoopBack (or something) and than the Pod is live again. I have just noticed that. The question was answered actually. If you want to write the answer so others can learn as well it will be good.

Comment: What then is your question? Apparently I misunderstood something.

Comment: I said that after I have posted the question I found the answer bymyself so the case is "closed". But answer is still welcome, so others can learn

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you changed the comment. No problem, glad your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `ReplicaSet` (`Deployment` is also a `ReplicaSet`), then after the application crashes, the pod will also crash, as a result of which the `ReplicaSet` will create a new pod.

PS: I think it's obvious that `uncaughtException` occurs when there are uncaught exceptions in your code (not in `promises` and `async/await`). To prevent this event from being raised, you need to add exception handlers wherever exceptions might be thrown.